# URL Based routing on Azure

Tags: azure, api

I am trying to do URL based routing for my APIs but I am not able to achieve as my API endpoints contain a wildcard in the middle of the URL, like:

- /prodapi/v1.0/{appId}/level
- /prodapi/v1.0/{appId}/products

appId is my customers white label ID, so it's unique for all our customers.

So far I have tried :

- Azure application gateway  [ But you can only handle at the end of your URL]
- Azure Fron door [Have the same settings]
- API management [ Not allowing me to do wildcard]

Can someone help me with any azure native or Out of the box solution.

Comment: Hello! Do I understand you correctly that you want to route to different backends? For example appId 1 to one server, and appId 2 to another?

Comment: As mentioned AppID is going to be different for every customer for example : customer a will use /prodapi/v1.0/abcdefghijklmnop/products, Customer B will use /prodapi/v1.0/zxcvbnm/products . but they need to go to the same backend

Answer (score 0):

If you want to route the traffic depending on a specific path parameter, you could use Api management service and write a inbound policy as such:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="appId" value="@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["appId"])" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(int.Parse(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("appId")) == 1)">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://google.com/" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(int.Parse(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("appId")) == 2)">
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://twitter.com/" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service base-url="https://facebook.com/" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Replacing the backend-service with your prefer url ofc :)

API management is very powerful, so I'm sure that you'll find the solution there if this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: As mentioned AppID is going to be different for every customer for example :  customer a will use /prodapi/v1.0/abcdefghijklmnop/products, Customer B will use /prodapi/v1.0/zxcvbnm/products . but they need to go to the same backend.

Comment: @Tushar In what language / framework are you writing your backend? What you are trying to achieve is a common problem and most frameworks can handle it :)